# A number is inserted in an edittext can not insert in the other edittext remaining

Tags: android

I have 9 `EditText`as shows the image if I underneath when inserting a number in an `EditText` I can not insert this number another time in other `EditText` remaining for example if I insert 5 in et0 I can not insert 5 other times in et1, et2, ...., et8 I'm doing a test but the problem if for example inserts 1 and I want to insert 10 it tells me that 1 repeats itself.

[image]

here is the code that I use

```
public void editTextWatcher(final EditText edt) {
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText("");
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            texts.add(et1.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et2.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et3.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et4.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et5.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et6.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et7.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et8.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et9.getText().toString());

            for (String text : texts) {
                if (s.toString().equals(text)) {
                    if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
                    animation1.setDuration(70);
                    animation1.setStartOffset(500);
                    animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                    edt.startAnimation(animation1);
                    edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    afficheerr1();

                    return;

                }
            }

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText(s.toString());
            edt.setSelection(edt.getText().length());
            edt.findFocus();
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just try keeping record of entered text. Like create one `ArrayList` and add text entered into `EditText` into `ArrayList`. when user enters any text into `EditText` check for that text into `ArrayList`. If that text found perform action accordingly.

Comment: What is the `inputType` for each `Edittext`? I assume its `number`?

Comment: thanks. yes, there are numbers

Comment: The problem here if user enter a two digit number then you can not block user if the first digit is already used . So this will make the case that we should examine the validity of number after user input (Probably  in focus change). Got it ?

Comment: yes that's exactly my problem

Comment: Yeah this can not be done with `TextWatcher` because we can not assume that how many digits are going to enter . So do all the validation on Focus change listener .  This is my concern maybe there is a better way around for this .

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

While entering, if it is a same number set error message. Then user understand number already exists.

```
edt.setError("same number");
```

Focus change listener check again last entered number is already entered or not.
If entered clear last entered number in last entered edit text and show Toast message to user understand.

```
String lastEnter="";

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        lastEnter=s.toString();

    }

myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {

                    for (String text : texts) {
                        if (lastEnter.toString().equals(text)) {
                            myEditText.setText("");
                            android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered number already exists, we removed, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        });
```